# How can the compiler differentiate between the following?

Tags: c++, vector, containers

Take a look at this...http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert
How can the compiler differentiate between the 3rd and the 4th i.e., between whether to make the no.of copies of the desired int or to fill up, the container in the provided range.

```
// 3rd
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value );

// 4th
template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just so we are all on the same wavelength, I edited in the overload you speak about (taking the C++11 ones arbitrarily, the answer should be identical whether using C++11 or not).

Comment: @BjörnPollex Given `std::vector<double>`, overload resolution of `v.insert( it, 2, 0 )` will cause the template function (option 4) to be chosen, at least in C++03.  (In C++11, the wording is different, and requires the template function to be excluded from overload resolution any time the type does not meet the requirements of an iterator.  In C++03, the wording requires the the template form to have the same behavior as the non-template form if `InputIt` resolves to an integral type.)

Answer (score 2):

It's the compiler's (or the library writer's) problem, not
yours.  The standard says that if the `InputIt` types are such
that the form 3 could be called, the behavior should be as if
the form 3 had been called.  Typically, some form of template
meta-programming is used, so that the template functions
taking iterators will forward to two different functions, chosen
by overload resolution based on whether `InputIt` can be
converted implicitly to a `size_type` or not (C++03), or whether
`InputIt` would be a legal iterator (C++11).

Answer (score 0):

An `iterator` and a `const_iterator` are not the same class at all. The compiler then has no problem to deduce what overloaded version it has to use.

EDIT: the second and last argument, in the 4th version has to be the same, and must follow the concept of `InputIterator`. It’s **not** the case of size_t, there’s no ambiguity.

Comment: Let us say that this is the code to be executed then. just by looking at it how can you tell whether it's the first case or the second one mylist.insert (it,2,20);

Comment: First, your edit only concerns C++11; in C++03, the criteria (IIRC) was whether the type `InputIterator` was an integral type.  And you don't really explain what was asked: how does the compiler make the distinction.